# Startin HBase Shell - Zookeeper exists but fails

Tags: linux, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run HBase on Ubuntu.  I've installed it and can start it (it throws some warning because I'm using a 64-bit system but I'm told I can ignore these).  However, when I try to start the shell I get the error messages below, but I'm new to this so am struggling to figure it out.  It says that Zookeeper exists but has failed 4 times - do you know why?

```
2015-12-03 12:34:37,796 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-12-03 12:34:54,551 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2015-12-03 12:34:54,552 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x2b289ac90x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:362)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:58)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:191)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:822)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:249)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.jordan.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_2.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/jordan/hbase-1.1.2/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118)
    at home.jordan.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_2.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/home/jordan/hbase-1.1.2/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:697)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:690)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:597)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:446)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:369)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:258)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:224)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
2015-12-03 12:34:54,556 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x2b289ac90x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:362)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:58)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:191)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:822)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:249)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.jordan.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_2.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/jordan/hbase-1.1.2/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118)
    at home.jordan.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_2.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/home/jordan/hbase-1.1.2/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:697)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:690)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:597)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:446)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:369)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:258)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:224)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
```

Answer (score 6):

This issue may happen due to one or all of the following issues:

1. **Configuration issue in hbase-site.xml**: open hbase-site.xml in an editor of your choice and make sure the following properties are set properly (assuming you setup HDFS and created /hbase directory in there),

```html
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2182</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/var/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>localhost:60000</value>
    <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

If you are using a local directory as hbase.rootdir, please replace hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase to file:///${hbase.rootdir}.

2. **Configuration issue in hbase-env.sh**: open hbase-env.sh in text editor of your choice and remove the # tag from

   export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
3. **Zookeeper server not started**: start zookeeper by going to the zookeeper directory and execute the following at the terminal,

   bin/zkServer start

Finally, restart hbase once you are done with updating these configurations.

Comment: This worked for me specially because I am running it locally so I had to change the hdfs protocol with file and hbase started working. Port change also worked because main zkServer uses 2181 so we have to change the client port to 2182. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for saving my time @Teddy Belay

Answer (score 1):

First start Zookeeper manually:

```
cd /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6
bin/zkServer.sh start
```

Then start `Hbase`:

```
start-hbase.sh
```

Before that you have to provide necessary permissions to Zookeeper folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here was my resolution:

First you need to start your habse server, then you can start your hbase shell.

```
leiline@master:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ sh start-hbase.sh

leiline@master:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ hbase shell
```